# PyQt: Get the id of a specific QWizard page

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwizard

I order to design a non-linear wizard with pyqt4 I reimplemented the `nextId()` function from a `PyQt4.QtGui.QWizardPage`.

```
self.page1.nextId = self.nextId_page1

def nextId_page1(self):
    if radio_button.isChecked():
        return 2

    return 3
```

The code above works fine. But when I insert another page at the beginning of the wizard I need to change the return values (2 and 3) in the function above. I there any possibility to get the id of a specific page? I would like to have something like that:

```
def nextId_page1(self):
    if radio_button.isChecked():
        return get_id_of_page(name_of_page_2)

    return get_id_of_page(name_of_page_3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `self` refers to the QWizard:

```
def nextId_page1(self):
    if radio_button.isChecked():
        return self.currentId()+1

    return self.currentId()+2
```

This is the simple answer.

For arbitrary "go to page":

Note that adding your pages with `setPage` rather than `addPage` allows you to explicitly give IDs to each page. `page(i)` lets you retrieve each page by ID, and `pageIds` gets a list of currently used Ids; there doesn't seem to be an obvious "which ID is this page", but the two methods before would allow you to quickly find any given page.